# If 13 cards are dealt from a thoroughly shuffled deck of 52 ordinary playing cards, find the probability of getting five spades and four diamonds.

Tags: probability, combinations, card-games

I am using  $$\frac{\left(\frac{13!}{5!(13-5)!}\right)\left(\frac{13!}{4!(13-4)!}\right)\left(\frac{26!}{3!(13-3)!}\right)}{\left(\frac{52!}{13!(52-13)!}\right)}$$

but it seems I am doing something wrong here , the answer  in the text book key is 0.02166

but my calculation gives 0.0037

Comment: exactly $5$ spades or at least $5$ spades?

Comment: After choosing five spades and four diamonds, you need to choose four other cards. You have only chosen three. Otherwise, your approach is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a textbook example of a multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

Pick the five spades that occur in your hand.  $\binom{13}{5}$ options.

Pick the four diamonds that occur in your hand.  $\binom{13}{4}$ options.

Pick the four remaining non-spade non-diamond cards.  $\binom{26}{4}$ options.

Divide by the total number of hands possible.  $\binom{52}{13}$ options.

$$\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{13}{4}\binom{26}{4}}{\binom{52}{13}}\approxeq 0.21664206\dots$$

Comment: thanks , it makes sense. the mistake i made was with respect to last part where i considered 3! with 26! instead of 4. thanks for the help .